# Corruption bound of MPC when n>2

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, perfect-secrecy

In the book titled "Secure Multiparty Computation and Secret Sharing" stated that MPC protocol is not secure when the adversary $t>n/2$. This was proved by using a 2 party protocol, but I can't understand why the same applies when $n<2$.

For example, when $n=6$ and $t=3$, the adversary might know the multiplication of the output for the 3 honest players, but as long as their individual inputs are not known, doesn't that consider as secure?
Could someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

First, it's important to understand that MPC is not possible for $t \geq n/2$ in the information-theoretic setting (where the adversary is computationally unbounded). In the computational setting, where the adversary is polynomial-time, it is possible to achieve MPC under cryptographic hardness assumptions.

Regarding your specific question, I assume you are referring to a case where we have a polynomial of degree $t$ to share a secret. Indeed, it is possible to share a secret securely for any $t\leq n$. However, the problem is that you need to be able to process that secret. So, if $t=3$ and $n=6$ and you have a degree-3 polynomial, then the first step of multiplication yields a polynomial of degree-6. In order to reconstruct the values, 7 points are needed for a degree-6 polynomial. However, there are only 6 parties and only 6 points. So, this cannot be done.

Of course, the above just says why this approach doesn't work. However, it's possible to prove that no approach can work, and I believe that this also appears in the book.

Comment: Thank you Professor, but what if the multiplication is performed using another approach that does not increase the polynomial degree (for example, scalar value * polynomial), does the corruption bound still apply? And also, does this limitation also apply for addition using MPC?

Comment: @amin, are you saying you are doing a single operation, either scalar multiplication or addition?

Comment: @amin As I described in my answer, I only showed that the polynomial approach doesn't work. However, I also explained that it's possible to prove that no approach can work. You can find a proof of this in the book you mentioned.

Comment: @YehudaLindell Ohh, I get it. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @mikeazo yes, I'm curious whether by doing single operation such as scalar multiplication or addition would lead to the same limitation such as the one in polynomial multiplication.

Comment: @amin, I believe that doing only a single operation does not have that limitation.

Comment: @mikeazo, do you mean that the corruption bound does not apply for  single operation of scalar multiplication or addition but does apply for polynomial multiplication?

Comment: What do you mean by polynomial multiplication? Multiplying two encrypted polynomials that are encrypted?

Comment: The limitation is to securely compute essentially any "non-trivial" function. You should look at the proof (and papers) to understand this.

Comment: @mikeazo, what i mean by polynomial multiplication is the conventional method of multiplication using secret sharing, which polynomials derived using secret sharing are multiplied together. But, if the polynomials are first encrypted, doesn't that mean that it is possible to to achieve MPC when t≥n/2 under cryptographic hardness assumptions?

Comment: @YehudaLindell, from what I understand from your explanation, any function could not be securely compute when the adversary exceeded the limitation, and the only way to overcome this is by using the computational setting, such as encryption of the secret. Is this correct?

Comment: @YehudaLindell, I read some of the answer regarding the same problem and found out about this: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34086/49934. What do you mean by security is maintained in the answer?

Comment: @amin Under cryptographic assumptions, it is possible to achieve secure computation for any $t<n$. So, yes, it is possible to do anything, even with $t\geq n/2$ (again, under cryptographic hardness assumptions).

Comment: So a new paper just came out [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/718.pdf) that is relevant to the discussion. The English is a little rough, but they appear to be claiming information theoretic security even when $t\geq n/2$ (in the semi-honest setting). So either their paper is flawed or my understanding of their claim is flawed.

Comment: This impossibility is a classic result of Chor and Kushilevitz. The paper is called "A Zero-One Law for Boolean Privacy" and the link is http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0404004 (unfortunately it's not open). So, I don't know exactly what the new paper does, but Chor-Kushilevitz is a reliable result.

Comment: @YehudaLindell, agreed. Either I'm misunderstanding their claim or their claim is incorrect. I need to read through it to figure out which it is.

Comment: @mikeazo, thank you for the suggestion. I'll try to read it.

Comment: @YehudaLindell, thank you for the explanation. Thanks to your explanation, I finally understood the meaning of the limitation in the book when assuming that n>2.